# Multiplying values from different tables linked by primary keys

Tags: mysql

[image: Image of tables]

I'd like to multiply values from two different tables(**transactions.quantity*prices.price**) which are connected by primary keys. I was trying to do it like this: 
select transactions.idd * prices.price join on discs transactions.idd = discs.idd join on prices discs.idp = prices.idp

Unfortunetely my knowledge from mysql is pretty bad and its obviously not working.

Can somebody help me to fix this query?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) the tables before doing the multiplications.

```
SELECT A.quantity, C.price, A.quantity*C.price cost
FROM transactions A JOIN disc B
ON A.idd=B.idd  JOIN prices C
ON B.idp=C.idp;
```

You did not include the disc table in your join, and the syntax of your query is wrong.